# Correct way to mark HTML text as decorative with ARIA

Tags: html, accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers

In an earlier version of the http://getbootstrap.com/components/#pagination page/section, it had the code:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous"><a href="#"><span role="presentation">&larr;</span> Older</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

This has been changed to:

```
<nav>
  <ul class="pager">
    <li class="previous"><a href="#"><span aria-hidden="true">&larr;</span> Older</a></li>
    ...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The left arrow (&larr;) is purely decorative, and doesn't need to be announced by a screen reader. According to http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/roles#presentation:

> presentation (role)
>
> Example use cases:
>
> An element whose content is completely presentational (like a spacer image, decorative graphic, or clearing element);
>
> An image that is in a container with the img role and where the full text alternative is available and is marked up with aria-labelledby and (if needed) aria-describedby;
>
> ...

Whereas:

> aria-hidden (state)
>
> Indicates that the element and all of its descendants are not visible
>   or perceivable to any user as implemented by the author.

I understand that 'role=presentation' is really talking about the *semantic* meaning of the element, but it seems like the left arrow is directly analogous to 'a spacer image, decorative graphic, or clearing element', and is certainly 'visible or perceivable to any user'.

What's the correct design pattern here? Is the meaning of 'aria-hidden' changing to allow for this specific limitation of 'role=presentation'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The role attribute is used to override the default mapping of the role of the HTML element to the accessibility tree. This has no effect on the text content of the element.

For example, role="button" on a div will allow the div to be announced as a button but will not change the fact that the text of the div (e.g. "Submit") will still be announced as the accessible name.

In ARIA 1.1 the presentation role has been given a synonym of "none" to better represent its semantic http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria-1.1/#none

The attribute aria-hidden is used to hide the element itself and the content (accessible name) of the element from the accessibility tree while keeping it visible in the document. This semantic has always been the case. It has not changed.

Comment: Thanks @unobf, that's really helpful! It seems like ARIA 1.1 is clearing up exactly this situation, with role="none" and a change to the description of aria-hidden (since "not visible or perceivable to any user as implemented by the author" isn't a good description of this situation).

Answer (score 1):

unobf is correct but sometimes it helps if you think of what the screen reader user will experience.  Consider this simple example:

```
<div role='button' tabindex=0>alpha</div>
<br>
<div role='presentation' tabindex=0>beta</div>
<br>
<div role='button' tabindex=0>gamma</div>
<br>
<div role='button' tabindex=0 aria-hidden='true'>delta</div>
<br>
<div role='button' tabindex=0>epsilon</div>
```

If you're using VoiceOver or the virtual PC cursor in JAWS, both will allow you to put your focus on the role='presentation' item and will not state a role but it will say 'beta'.  (I like the new role='none' that unobf points out in the 1.1 spec.  It makes it clearer that the screen reader should not state any role when it's set to 'none'.  As the spec says, it was a little confusing using 'presentation'.)  So the presentation item isn't really hidden to the screen reader.  You're just telling the screen reader that it doesn't have a role.

Aria-hidden, on the other hand, completely removes it from the screen reader, except in my poor example (which is intentional).  If you're using VoiceOver or the virtual PC cursor in JAWS, both will skip the aria-hidden button.  The screen reader user won't know it's there.  But if the JAWS user is TABBING through the page, they *will* land on the aria-hidden button because it's a tab stop.  But since it's aria-hidden, JAWS gets a little confused on what to say.  When I tried it (FF 38 and JAWS 16), it said 'beta', which is the text from a previous `<div>`.  In general, you don't want to aria hide something but make it keyboard accessible.  That's just a weird scenario.

Going back to bootstrap's old example, since they used role='presentation' and it's a `<span>` tag, the VoiceOver and virtual PC cursor JAWS user will both be able to put their focus on the `<span>` element, which is probably not what they intended.  Since the arrow is just for decoration, it makes sense to aria hide it.

Comment: aria-hidden will not hide tab focussable content. If you are using it to do this, you need to set tabindex on all tab focussable items to -1 when you set aria-hidden to true. An example of a page that does this is http://dylanb.github.io/periodic-aria11-roles.html where if you click one of the roles and the modal pops up, the anchors are all set to tabindex=-1 in addition to aria-hidden being set to true

Comment: exactly.  that was the point of my example.  I also meant to point out the "4th rule of aria use" - http://www.w3.org/TR/aria-in-html/#fourth-rule-of-aria-use